# Pandas resample Multi-Index

Tags: python, pandas

My data is monthly and has two indices - Date and Id:

```
Date          Id   Value
2016-01-01    1    1.14
              2    4.12
         ........
2016-02-01    1    1.15
              2    4.11
         ........
```

I want to Up-Sample my dataset to daily with forward fill.
I've tried with `ds.asfreq('D', method='ffill')` but I guess because of the `Id` axis it won't work.

Is there a workaround ?